# reinterpret_cast<double**> SEG fault

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, pointers

I am trying the following code for multi-dimensional array. It gives `SEG` error
I do not know what is the issue in this.

```
 static void read(double **arr){
  //REQ arr to be pointing to  array[5][4] 
  //EFF prompt the use to input the data
  //Mod array pointer by **arr
       int i(0) , j(0);
       double tmp ;


       for(i=0 ; i<4 ; i++){

            for(j=0 ; j<5 ; j++) {
                cout <<"Please enter Data#"<<  (j+1) << " File#" << (i+1)  <<" "<<flush;

                cin >> tmp ; 
                arr[j][i] = tmp ;
            }   

        }

        return ; 
    }


int main(){
 double arr[5][4] ;
 read(reinterpret_cast<double**>(arr) ) ;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there any reinterpret_cast in C?

Comment: @NishithJainMR This isn't C. I don't know why he used that tag.

Comment: Arrays in C++ are not implemented as pointers to pointers. It is implemented as a contiguous section of memory. So `arr[2][3]` Is more likely to be equivalent to `arr + 2*(sizeof(int)*4) + 3*sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 5):

You are using `2D array` which is stored the same way as linear arrays (the dimensions are used for indexing only), however you are interpreting is as an `pointer to (array of) pointer(s) to (array of) double(s)`, which has completely different memory layout. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673719/memory-map-for-a-2d-array-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory) SO question.

Answer (score 3):

An array of arrays is **not** the same as a pointer to pointer.

Lets look at how they are laid out in memory:

Array of arrays:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+
| arr[0][0] | arr[0][1] | ... | arr[0][3] | arr[1][0] | ... | arr[4][3] |
+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+
```

Compare to pointer-to-pointer (e.g. `double** arr`):

```
+-----+      +--------+--------+-----+
| arr | ---> | arr[0] | arr[1] | ... |
+-----+      +--------+--------+-----+
                 |        |
                 |        `------.
                 |               |
                 v               v
             +-----------+   +-----------+
             | arr[0][0] |   | arr[0][1] |
             +-----------+   +-----------+
```

---

The solution is to change your function so it either takes an array of arrays:

```
void read(double arr[][4]) { ... }
```

Or a pointer to an array (this works because arrays decays to pointers):

```
void read(double (*arr)[]) { ... }
```

Then you can pass the array without casting:

```
double arr[5][4];
read(arr);
```

Comment: void read(double (*arr)[]) { ... }

I have tried it but I have compilation error . It doesn't work

Thank you for your help