# C++ - pointers in multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've bought a beginners book for visual c++ and have come the chapter which involves arrays, strings and pointers. I understand the concept, but when it comes to multidimensional arrays I got a bit lost.

Array and and pointer declaration:

```
double beans[3][4];
double* pbeans;
```

I understood this part:

*You can declare and assign a value to the pointer pbeans, as follows:

```
double* pbeans;
pbeans = &beans[0][0];
```

But when the author presents that you can assign the address for the first row/dimension by typing this statement he lost me:

```
pbeans = beans[0];
```

Why can we skip the "Address-Of" operator here?
To me the logical thing would be:

```
pbeans = &beans[0];
```

Comment: [This FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810664/1202636) is really useful if you're fighting with arrays, pointers and theri relationships.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because an array decays to a pointer to the first element.  If we have an array called `arr`, then any usage of `arr` where an array won't fit will generally result in `arr` being treated as a pointer.  This is called decay.

In this case, `beans[0]` is an array; to be specific, an `double[4]`.  However, as you cannot assign an array to a pointer, the array decays into a `double*`.

The code you provided, `double* pbeans = &beans[0];` would be trying to assign a pointer to an array of  doubles to a pointer to a double; that won't work due to a type mismatch.

Also, all that aside, this doesn't sound like a very good book; teaching arrays, strings and pointers together smells of C.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have just an array

```
double legumes[5];
```

Arrays decay to pointers so you can do

```
double* plegumes = legumes;
```

When you declare a 2d array, what you're doing is creating an array of arrays. So the expression `beans[0]` actually refers to an array. So the statement

```
pbeans = beans[0];
```

Is just assigning an array to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard conversion between array types and pointers to the first element of the array. As a simpler example:

```
int array[5];
int* p = array;
```

`p` is now a pointer to the first element of `array`, because objects of type "array of 5 int" will *decay* to a "pointer to `int`" if they need to.

In your case, `beans[0]` is of type "array of 4 double" and will decay into a "pointer to double" that points at the first element in the `beans[0]` array. It is equivalent to doing `double* p = &beans[0][0]`.