# Pointers/Multi-dimensional Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Im having a little trouble understanding pointers.If I declare a multi-dimensional array `char ma[10][30]`. What is the address of the element `"ma[2][20]"`? if the address must be assigned to the pointer variable, that's not `"p = &ma[2][20]"`.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810676/964135 helps

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory - it confirms what PQuinn said, but also includes an important warning about how to access...

Comment: @ Pubby & Floris Thanks that really helps me visualize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multidimensional array is really just a contiguous chunk of memory. In this case the array is a chunk of chars (bytes) 10*30 = 300 bytes in size. The compiler is handling the accessing of this array via the two 'dimensions'.

The address of ma[2][20] is the address of 'ma' + 2*30 + 20 or 'ma+80' bytes. 'ma' is the address of the start of the chunk of memory representing the array.

Comment: Not sure that is always true. The compiler can allocate chunks of memory that are pointed to by ma[n] and that are not contiguous. In other words, I don't think compilers **guarantee** that ma[n][29] is right before ma[n+1][0], although in practice that is often the case.

Comment: This will always be true. If there is a compiler out there that violates this, only seriously masochistic crazies should ever use it.

Comment: @PQuinn - valid point about "masochistic crazies". But see my earlier link to a more detailed discussion about this.

Answer (score 2):

The address of `ma[2][20]` is `ma[2] + 20`
since `ma` is a character array

or `p = &(ma[2][20])` - pretty sure the brackets matter...

Comment: +1 The parens do not matter in the second parse: `&ma[2][10]` will work equally well (apart from the OP specifically requesting a *different* answer than that, which you also supplied).

Answer (score 0):

In static arrays, the memory allocation is contiguous. It can be elaborated via the following example
int arr[2][5]= {  {1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9,10}};
cout<