# How is a three dimensional array stored in memory?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

How is a three dimensional array stored in memory?

For example, a two dimensional array is stored in terms of rows and columns `d[rows][columns];`
in the case of three a dimensional array `d[?][?][?]` how are the elements arranged in c?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

Multidimensional arrays are laid out contiguously in memory, not as rows and columns.

For eg. 
If you have

```
Array[5][2]={{0,1},{2,3},{4,5},{6,7},{8,9}};
```

It'll be stored in memory as:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
```

and not as:

```
| 0 | 1 | 
| 2 | 3 | 
| 4 | 5 | 
| 6 | 7 | 
| 8 | 9 |
```

And a 3D array is essentially an array of 2D arrays:
ie

```
Array[2][5][2]= Array_1[5][2], Array_2[5][2]
```

If

```
Array_1[5][2]={{0,1},{2,3},{4,5},{6,7},{8,9}};
```

and

```
Array_2[5][2]={{10,11},{12,13},{14,15},{16,17},{18,19}};
```

So, in memory this 3D array will be laid out as:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
```

Comment: Exactly. A 3D array is simply an array of arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

C uses row-major layout.  When 2D array (i.e. matrix) is linearized, the first row is stored first, then the second row, the third row then follows and so on.  Similarly for N-dimensional arrays.