# Output prints address instead of value in a pointer of 3D array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to declare a 3D array and store value into the 3D array using pointer. But I can get the inputs using scanf but the output always prints the address instead of the value of the array. Below is my code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
   int b[3][3][3];
   int l1,l2,l3;
   int *pa2[3][3];

   pa2[3][3]=b;

   for(l1=0;l1<3;l1++)
   {
      for(l2=0;l2<3;l2++)
      {
         for(l3=0;l3<3;l3++)
         {
            scanf("%d",(((pa2+l1)+l2)+l3));
         }
      }
   }

   for(l1=0;l1<3;l1++)
   {
      for(l2=0;l2<3;l2++)
      {
         for(l3=0;l3<3;l3++)
         {
            printf("%d\n",*(((pa2+l1)+l2)+l3));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh  Actually there is . See scanf part below .

Comment: You are using `void main` and have tagged a C question with the C++ tag. Those two things are most wrong about the question! :)

Comment: Simply adding l1, l2, and l3 is wrong. We need to multiply and add to get the correct addresses.

Comment: Please note that a 3D-array in C is an array of an array of an array.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax No multiplication is needed.

Comment: `int *pa2[3][3]; pa2[3][3]=b;` does not look right, no matter what the language...

Comment: your code has bugs. During the loop execution `l1=0,l2=0,l3=1` and `l1=0,l2=1,l3=0`will modify the same memory location.

Comment: `(((pa2+l1)+l2)+l3))` is equivalent to `(pa2 + l1 + l2 + l3)`, so `*(((pa2+l1)+l2)+l3)` is equivalent to `pa2[l1 + l2 + l3]`. (`&pa2[0]`, which `pa2` decays into,  is an `int*(*)[3]`,  and pointer arithmetic doesn't ever result in a different pointer type.)

Comment: I just updated my answer with usage of multiplication... Just for the sake of argument ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use pointer `pa2` at all? Use

```
scanf("%d",&b[l1][l2][l3]);
```

and

```
printf("%d\n",b[l1][l2][l3]);
```

If you insist on using points, you need to get the pointer arithmetics right. Array memory is laid out continuously (compare [How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)). The following example would do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a[3][4][5];
    void *p = a;

    int x = 0;
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            for(k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {
                a[i][j][k] = x++;
            }
        }
    }

    const size_t s = sizeof(int);
    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            for(k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {
                printf("%d ", *(int*)(p + 20*i*s + 5*j*s + k*s));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of pointer `pa` to access the array is wrong in both the `scanf` line and the `printf` line.

You have

```
scanf("%d",(((pa2+l1)+l2)+l3));
```

What does `(((pa2+l1)+l2)+l3)` evaluate to?

It is simply `(pa2+l1+l2+l3)`. I am sure that's not what you meant to do. By using this, you have a program that is subject to undefined behavior.

You can use:

```
&(pa2[l1][l2][l3])
```

If you insist on using the less clear form, you'll need to use:

```
(*(*(pa2+l1) + l2) + l3)
```

For the `printf` statement, you can use:

```
printf("%d\n", pa2[l1][l2][l3]);
```

or

```
printf("%d\n", *(*(*(pa2+l1)+l2)+l3));
```

**Update**

The declaration of `pa2` and the line to set its are also wrong.

Instead of

```
int *pa2[3][3];
pa2[3][3]=b;
```

You need:

```
   int (*pa2)[3][3];    
   pa2=b;
```

or a one liner:

```
   int (*pa2)[3][3] = b;
```

Comment: `&(pa2[l1][l2][l3])`  due to this program crashes while taking input. Please check it once more.

Answer (score 0):

A 3D-array is an array of an array of an array, hence after adding the offset to the pointer you need to dereference it and start over:

```
*(*(*(pa + l1) + l2) + l3)
```

this is equivalent to:

```
pa[l1][l2][l3]
```