# How to print a 2D-array in C, without using the operator []?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax-error

I am trying to print a 2D matrix with using `[]`, **instead I want to use `*` like a pointer.**
So with a 1 D array I'd do: `*(arr+i)` for example.
What's the syntax used to replace in `matrix[][]` ?

Here's the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < (size * 2); j++)
    {
        printf(" %5d", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

P.S,
I did try several things like:

```
*(matrix+i+j);
*(matrix+i)+*(matrix+j);
```

Of course none of that worked.

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Is matrix `T[][]` or `T**` ?

Comment: I recommend that you use pointer syntax only for learning purposes. Array syntax should be preferred, as it's simpler and easier to understand. Some people think pointer syntax is more effective, but in truth they are both equally fast.

Comment: Good point, I am actually just doing an exercise form studies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may depend on how `matrix` was allocated or passed to a function.

```
int A[10][15];
```

This uses a contiguous block of memory. To address the elements without using array notation use:

```
        A +(i*15)+j    // user694733 showed this is wrong
((int *)A)+(i*15)+j    // this is horribly ugly but is correct
```

Note the 15, as each row consists of 15 elements. Better solutions are presented in other answers here.

In the following:

```
int *A[10];
```

`A` is an array of 10 pointers to ints. Assuming each array element has been allocated using `malloc`, you address the elements without using array notation as:

```
*(A+i) + j;
```

that is, you take `A`, then take the `i`th element, dereference that and add `j` as the second index.

--EDIT--

And to be complete:

```
int foo(int *p)
```

here a function just receives a pointer to zero or more ints.  The pointer points to a contiguous, linear block of memory into which you can place an n-dimensional array. How many dimensions there are and the upper bound of each dimension the function can only know through parameters or global variables.

To address the cells of the n-dimensional array, the programmer must calculate the addresses him/herself, using the above notation.

```
int foo3(int *m, int dim2, int dim3, int i,  int j, int k)
{
    int *cell = m + i*dim3*dim2 + j*dim2 + k;
    return *cell;
}
```

Comment: Using `A+(i*15)+j` is error prone and unnecessary. It's only needed if you allocate 2D as 1D array.

Comment: @user694733, all arrays of the form `int A[10][15]` are contiguous in memory. That has nothing to do with "allocating a 2D as 1D array." I can treat any contiguous block of memory as an n-dimensional array. It is just to show the OP how to do it. It is not nice, but that's what he wants to learn.

Comment: `*(*(matrix+i)+j)` does it without needing to specify the size explicitly.

Comment: @user694733, I'd like to see this when the array is of variable size and passed as a pointer such as `foo(int *A, int size1)`. Without knowing the dimensions at compile time, C can't solve it and the addressing must be as `A+(i*size1)+j`

Comment: By variable size I guess you mean allocated with `malloc`? If so, then either it's array of pointers to arrays (also known as jagged arrays) or 1D array used as 2D array. For former you can do the `*(*(A+i)+j)`, and for latter you must do `A+(i*N)+j`. But neither it's not the same as *"true"* 2D array, defined as `int A[10][15]`.

Comment: Your "true" 2D array, defined as int A[10][15]" is just a contiguous block of memory and the compiler uses the `A+(i*N)+j` calculation.

Comment: Perhaps it does so *internally*. But if you do it manually, then types are all wrong, unless you add casting. For variable `int m[2][2];` accessing last element `m[1][1]` using syntax `m+(i*size)+j`, now `m+(1*2)+1`, will expand to `(char*)&m[0] + sizeof(int[2]) * ((1*2)+1)`, which is **out of array bounds**. [Example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/47IdI7).

Comment: @user694733, I see... The type is `int[2]` where my premises was the type was just `int`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `*` two times. Each of `*` will basically replace one `[]`:

```
*(*(matrix+i)+j)
```

Comment: @Pixelchemist No it's not. It works due to array decaying into pointer.

Comment: It's correct because the array *does not* decay into a pointer.

Comment: @user694733 Why would array decay to pointer here ? ( _if not previously declared a pointer_).

Comment: @ameyCU user694733 is correct. Rhetorical question: how can you have pointer arithmetic without pointers?

Comment: If you have a pointer, Paul Ogilvie's addressing works, but *only if* you have a pointer. This on the other hand works *only* when the array is not a pointer.

Comment: Array `matrix` with type `int[][]` decays to pointer `&matrix[0]` with type `int(*)[]` (I hope I wrote that right) before `+i` is performed.

Comment: @2501 That's fine , writing `matrix`  will point to base element but that's not decaying (_if I am not wrong_).

Comment: @ameyCU; It's called decaying. `*(*(matrix+i)+j)` an expression and in this expression `matrix` decay to pointer to it's first element which will again decay to its first element (an `int`).

Comment: @alain : this will work in any case as this dereferencing holds the type of the expression. So after applying the first `+` the expression type will become `int (*)[15]`, after another the type will be `int *`. Similarly to pointer of pointers - it will be `int **` and after another `+` will become `int *` again.

Comment: @hacks I don't mean to be stubborn but your last comment come to me as dereferencing and decaying as same thing .

Comment: N1570 chapter 6.5.2.1 has example of subscripting array `int x[3][5];` with sentence: *"...In the expression `x[i]`, which is equivalent to `(*((x)+(i)))`, `x` is first converted to
a pointer to the initial array of five ints. ..."*

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000 What I meant is it doesn't work with `(int*)matrix`

Comment: @ameyCU; OK. Let it be clear. The expression `*(*(matrix+i)+j)` is perfectly valid whether `matrix` is an *array of arrays* of *pointer to pointer*. In case of 2D array, in the expression `*(matrix+i)`, `matrix` will decay to pointer to `matrix[0]`. So, `*(matrix+i)` is equivalent to `*(&matrix[0] + i)`. `&matrix[0] + i` will give the address of `matrix[i]`. Now `(matrix+i)` is equivalent to `&matrix[i]`. Dereferencing `&matrix[i]` will result in array `matrix[i]`. Now `matrix[i]` is an array itself, so it will decay to pointer to `matrix[i][0]`. `&matrix[i][0] + j` will give.....

Comment: @hacks This clears it up between the terms (_my confusion between them_) . Thanks :-)

Comment: @Puck; No, it will not work. `*(matrix+i*size+j)` will launch you somewhere in the space.

Comment: @hacks: tried it and noticed it. But why? I fought 2D matrix in C was simply a bigger 1D matrix, as explained here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory?lq=1). And I am quiet sure I used trick like that during courses on C...

Comment: @Puck `*((int*)matrix + i*size + j)` should work. The problem is that `matrix` is a pointer to a 1D-array.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this-

```
*(*(matrix+i)+j)  //reduce level of indirection by using *
```