# Array without the use of [] index operator

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Currently i'm looking for a way, to solve a task.
I'm looking for a way to use the following expression, but without [] index operators.

```
V[i][k]
```

In this case it's quite easy, when i have `V[k]`it can be expressed through `*(V + k)`. Maybe something like `*(V + i + k)` ?
But how can i do this in the same way for a multi-dimension array in C? I'm also not allowed to use the ampersand operator, so i hope someone could help.

Comment: Just iterate what you already know: `*(*(V+i)+k)`

Comment: Seemingly [this thread of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312840/how-to-print-a-2d-array-in-c-without-using-the-operator) answers your question.