# difference between int a[9] and a[3][3]

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is the difference between

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[9]; 

int
main()
{
    printf("%d\n", a[1]);
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[3][3]; 

int
main()
{
  printf("%d\n", a[1]);
}
```

I think both result in placing same 36 byte memory buffer in `.bss` section, what is the difference? Or is `a[3][3]` syntactic sugar over `a[9] - a[3*3]`?

Comment: Try declaring as `a[9]` and printing `a[0][0]`.

Comment: Looks to me that one is an array a[9] and the other one is a matrix a[3][3]. First is an array of 9 elements and the other is and array of 3 arrays of 3 elements

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research at all.

Comment: Some good info here, possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2565048/6273251

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

Comment: We cannot just look at the byte allocation and assume it is same. One is a 1D array another is a 2D array. If we go by byte allocation, then int x=100000 and int x=900000 will use same number of bytes but you see they do differ

Comment: If you'd *run* the two pieces of code you posted, you would have seen they give different results. Downvoting.

Comment: @kfsone and the output will be based on UB. You can never _rely_ on the output unless you _know_ your code. Just sayin'. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Are you referring to the '%d'?

Comment: @kfsone certainly, I am.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Well, if he'd tried compiling and running his code the compiler would have annotated that :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks, this comment will self-destroy in a minute. :)

Comment: "this comment will self-destroy in a minute. :) – Sourav Ghosh **12 mins ago**"  8-)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int a[3][3]` is a *semantic sugar* of sorts over `int a[9]`. The raw memory layout it the same (i.e. it is a contiguous block of 9 `int`s), but the language-level access syntax is different. When accessing `a[3][3]` as `a[i][j]`, the apparent 2D-indexing is converted by the compiler to 1D indexing using `i * 3 + j` formula. The latter index translation scheme is easily extendable to any number of dimensions.

Comment: Does not it mean that multi-dimensional static arrays are redundant because we can always convert them to one-dimensional? I mean, is multidimensional arrays are only there to ease programming and not to bother with index/offsets counting?

Comment: @Bulat M.: Yes, exactly. In that sense they are redundant. You can always replace a built-in multi-dimensional array with a single-dimentional one, in which case you will have to implement the above index translation scheme manually.

Comment: But why cannot we pass int[9] array to function that accepts as a parameter two-dimensional array?

Comment: @BulatM.: Because they're different types. (For that matter, we can't pass arrays to functions at all; C has no parameters of array type.) Just because `int[9]` and `int[3][3]` have the same memory layout, that doesn't mean  you can perform the same operations on them.

Comment: @Bulat M.: Multi-dimentsional arrays are not qualitiatively different from single-dimensional ones. From the language point of view `int[3][3]` array is actually a single dimensional array `T[3]`, in which `T` just happens to be an `int[3]`. I.e. it is a single-dimensional array of single-dimensional arrays. So, from the language point of view allowing to pass `int[3][3]` array as `int[9]` array is like allowing to pass some `T[3]` as `int[9]`. These types are not really related, if you look at them that way. They just happen to have the same size.

Comment: But you said that `int a[3][3]` is semantic sugar over `int a[9]`. Now you say they're not really related.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: What I meant is that the differences exist only at the language level. The raw memory blocks are organized indenticaly and whatever differences exist, they exist only as language concepts (be that multi-dimensional access or C type system). This is why I called it *semantic* sugar instead of *syntactic* sugar.

Comment: Does `int a[3][3]` vs. `int b[9]`. impose different memory constants concerning "one past"?  I do not _think_ so - so maybe this concern does not apply.   `&b[9]` must be a valid pointer value, as does `&a[3]`  and `&a[2][3]`.  Seems all are the same address. Hmmm.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, they are **not** same, they represent different types. In reference to your code,

- In the first case, `a` is an one dimensional array. Hence, `a[1]` is of type `int`.

  §)  To print the value, `%d` is fine.
- In the second case, however, `a` is a two-dimensional array. Hence, `a[1]` is of type `int [3]`.

  §)  When passed as a function argument, it decays to a pointer to the first element, basically a `int *`. You'll be needing `%p` to print that (*and cast the pointer to `void *`, as required by the `%p` format specifier*).

However, if you're bothered about the memory layout for both the variables, you can check the [other answer by AnT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537489/2173917) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2565039/2173917) which details about the memory layout of multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: It doesn't just have to be a function argument to decay: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/

Comment: @kfsone I know, that's why I mentioned _"In reference to your code"_. :)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between
>
> ```
> int a1[9];
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int a2[3][3];
> ```

(I've changed the names so I can talk about the declarations more easily.)

The difference is that they're of different types. They both have the same underlying memory layout,each consisting of a contiguous region of memory 9 times the size of an `int`. But `a1` is an array of 9 `int` objects, while `a2` is an array of 3 objects each of which is an array of 3 `int` objects. It's a multidimensional array, which in C is precisely an array of array, nothing more, nothing less.

The difference is not just syntactic sugar. You might get the same generated code for certain operations, for example `a1[1]` and `a2[0][1]`.  But, for example, `a1[3]` refers to the 4th element of the array `a1`, while `a2[0][3]`, though you might think it refers to the same thing, actually has undefined behavior. (Compilers are permitted, but not required, to perform run-time array bound checking, and are permitted to *assume* that array references do not go past the end of the indexed array object.)

```
printf("%d\n", a2[1]);
```

As others have mentioned, this has undefined behavior. `a2[1]` is an array object of type `int[3]`. An expression of array type is, in most contexts, converted to an expression of pointer type, so `a2[1]` ends up being of type `int*`, and yields a pointer to the initial element of the second row of `a2`. To print a pointer value, use `%p` -- which requires an argument of type `void*`, so you need to cast it:

```
printf("%p\n", a2[1]);
```

Recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Do you agree `&a2[0][3]` is well defined as well as `sizeof a2[0][3]`?  BTW, missing `(void*)` in `printf("%p\n", a2[1]);`.

Comment: @chux: Yes, the first because of the one-past-the-end rule, and the second because the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated (unless it's of VLA type).