# when setting value in double array with swaping row and col, got two cells valued. Why?

Tags: c++, arrays

with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define M 3
#define N 5
using namespace std;
int n;
int m;
int my_array[N][M];
void print_a(){
    cout << "array---------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << my_array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    n = N;
    m = M;
    int j = n - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        my_array[i][j] = i + j;
        print_a(); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> array---------------------------------
>   0 0 0 0 4
>   0 4 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0
>   array---------------------------------
>   0 0 0 0 4
>   0 4 0 0 5
>   0 5 0 0 0
>   array---------------------------------
>   0 0 0 0 4
>   0 4 0 0 5
>   0 5 0 0 6

tow cells in the double array are changed. I know that double array is also single array. so, even the col and row are exchanged. there should not be two cells are changed. It's Why?

Comment: You declare the array with N rows and M columns, but then you fill the array with a loop that goes over M rows and accesses column N-1

Comment: You have an array of arrays, and when you fill the values you go out of bounds of the nested array. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap n by m in your print function.

```
#include <iostream>
#define M 3
#define N 5
using namespace std;
int n;
int m;
int my_array[N][M];
void print_a(){
    cout << "array---------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            cout << my_array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    n = N;
    m = M;
    int j = n - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        my_array[i][j] = i + j;
        print_a(); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[it works.](http://ideone.com/4yWscx)

> ```
> array---------------------------------
> 0 0 0 
> 0 4 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> array---------------------------------
> 0 0 0 
> 0 4 0 
> 0 5 0 
> 0 0 0 
> 0 0 0 
> array---------------------------------
> 0 0 0 
> 0 4 0 
> 0 5 0 
> 0 6 0 
> 0 0 0
> ```

**Problem in your code:** The number in last column is actually next row's  value(second col). This is due to the cpp layout of 2D arrays on your machine. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Only one cell's value is changed, just because i print it twice!