# Creating matrix by indexing in c programming

Tags: matrix

How to represent 4D matrix in C code?
Is it possible to write code for 4D matrix? Any easy way please share.
So, that I can implement 5D matrix too.

Comment: The search term is [c multidimensional array](https://www.google.de/search?q=c+multidimensional+array). Give it a try!

Comment: So, can we write 4D array like A[x][y][z][w] ?

Comment: and if use this 4D array to a 1D array, Can we write like A[0][0][0][1]  or A[1][0][0][0] ?

Comment: To access one element of the 4D array, you write `A[x][y][z][w]`. If you are curious how the elements are stored in memory, you can read a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory).