# Is the meaning of [][] context-specific?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I always thought that x[i] is equivalent to `*(x+i)`.
So that would x[i][j] is equivalent to `*(*(x+i)+j)`, which is in this case implies that a 2D array *must* be implemented as an array of pointers, each of these pointers has to be dereferenced.

But I learned that you can create a 2D array on the heap this way :

```
char (*arr)[256]=malloc(512*256);
```

If the former hypothesis is right, then arr[i][j] would access an unauthorized location (since we are dereferencing two times).

Is my former hypothesis wrong in case of 2d arrays ?

Comment: 2D arrays such as `int a[3][4];` are not arrays of pointers - there are no pointers involved at all. They are arrays of arrays.

Comment: A "2d-array" is simply an array of arrays. Try drawing one out on paper and you will see that it all fits together as it should, even when using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: some good reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory

Comment: I see. I understand the array of arrays things, but wouldn't the solution of "array of pointers" have been a perfectly correct way of implementing 2D arrays, plus it is more consistent with the definition of [] ?

Comment: One of the primary tenets of arrays is that they are *contiguous* in memory. Therefore it follows that an array of arrays simple can not be an array of pointers (because then it's no longer contiguous).

Comment: Also, if you're to lazy to draw it out yourself, I have done it in [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456). There you can very easily see the difference between an array of arrays, and an array of pointers.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Actually when dereferencing an array or doing arithmetic on an array, **there are pointers involved**. Dereferencing and arithmetic cannot be done on an array. In fact there are exactly four operations on arrays: `&`, `sizeof`, `alignof` and conversion to a pointer to the first element. **Not more**. The latter is implicit for all operators than the listed.

Comment: @user2370139: An array of pointers is **not** a 2D array and cannot represent one! Read **and think about** my comment above!

Comment: The array has fixed size objects. What you may be missing is that you need to know at least the first dimension, in order to locate any index.

Comment: @Olaf Miss ping?  I don't think I said anything that contradicts what you said.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, sorry. Darn auto-completion :-)

Comment: @NeilButterworth: [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474058/is-the-meaning-of-context-specific?noredirect=1#comment74004016_43474058)  was for you actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `x[i]` is indeed equivalent to `*(x+i)`. Pointer arithmetic is used in the latter form.
- In case of a 2D array `type array[x][y];`, then you have to apply the above rule in several steps.
- `array` when used in an expression, decays to a pointer to the first element, in this case of type `type(*)[y]` - *an array pointer* pointing at the first array in the array of arrays. Do not confuse an array pointer with "an array of pointers", which means something different entirely.
- Therefore `array + i` performs pointer arithmetic on such an array pointer. `*(array + i)` gives the pointed-at item, a 1D array.
- If you for some reason unknown want to access an individual item in the 2D array by using pointer arithmetic only, you would therefore have to write something obscure like this:

  ```
  *( *(array + i) + j)
  ```

---

> If the former hypothesis is right, then arr[i][j] would access an
>   unauthorized location (since we are dereferencing two times).

Well, it wasn't right. When you have an array pointer such as `char (*arr)[256]`, then you can access the items as `arr[i][j]`. Note that `arr[i]` performs the same kind of pointer arithmetic, so you get "the char[256] array number `i`". And in that array you then access item `j`.

This is actually the reason why this syntax is used. Had you written the malloc more type correct like this:

```
char (*arr)[512][256]=malloc( sizeof(char[512][256]) );
```

then you would have to de-reference the array pointer before using it, `(*arr)[i][j]` or otherwise you would get pointer arithmetic on whole 2D arrays.

---

The question [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) explains and illustrates the differences between look-up tables based on arrays of pointers and true multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the details I got it now, my misunderstanding was that I always thought that when you do char arr[m][n]; arr is treated as char**, so it is an array of pointers with [] doing pointer arithmetic on a single char, which seems a reasonable way of implementing a 2D array.

Comment: @user2370139 Arrays and pointers are distinct types. It is just that arrays decay into a pointer to the first element whenever they are used in an expression.