# How do I access the memory using pointers for a multidimensional array?

Tags: c, pointers, debugging, multidimensional-array

I have been learning memory allocation and pointers lately, and I made this program which will ask the user to input the dimensions of a matrix and enter it's elements, after which it displays the elements in a matrix format. Here's the code that I've typed.

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"

int *minput();

int *minput(int x,int y)
{
    int *M;
    M=(int*)malloc(x*y*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<=(x-1);i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=(y-1);j++)
        {
            printf("A(%d,%d)=",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",(M+i+j));
        }
    }
    return M;
}

int main()
{
    int *A,a,b;
    printf("Matrix is (m*n)\n\n");
    printf("m=");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    A=minput(a,b);
    printf("\n");

    for(int k=0;k<=(a-1);k++)
    {
        for(int l=0;l<=(b-1);l++)
        {
            printf("%d ",*(A+k+l));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(A);
    return 0;
}
```

However when I gave my inputs, I got this:

```
Matrix is (m*n)

m=3
n=3
A(1,1)=1
A(1,2)=2
A(1,3)=3
A(2,1)=4
A(2,2)=5
A(2,3)=6
A(3,1)=7
A(3,2)=8
A(3,3)=9

1 4 7
4 7 8
7 8 9
```

What's wrong? Amn't I supposed to get

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Is there anything I had made wrong in my code?

Comment: Why `(A+k+l)`?.

Comment: Not relevant to your output, but `k<=(a-1)` is unusual. `k<a` is neater, equivalent, and the common idiom.

Comment: In calculating the indice you forget to multiply the row indice with the width.

Comment: `i<=(x-1)` -> `i < x`

Comment: `scanf("%d",(M+i+j));` does not read the element you think it does.

Comment: It's surprising how much of the time I've observed that giving variables a useful, meaningful name can help highlight flaws in the algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get incorrect output because `*(A+k+l)` is not the right way of accessing matrix element at `matrix[k][l]`.

For addressing a matrix stored as a "flat" array you need to multiply the value of one of the indexes by the size of the opposite dimension. Depending on which index you multiply you get either a row-major order or a column-major order.

You need to apply the same fix to `(M+i+j)` inside `minput` function.

```
// Input
scanf("%d",(M+y*i+j));
...
// Output
printf("%d ",*(A+b*k+l));
```

The idea behind multiplying `k` by `b` is to make `k` "count faster". For each increment of `k` by `1` you need to skip an entire row of `b` elements. In your three-column matrix example, if you would like to access elements at `A[k][0]` (the initial column) of your matrix for each row, your index would count by three: `0`, `3`, `6`. This is accomplished by multiplying `k` by `b`. The rest is the same as the usual pointer arithmetic: `*(A+b*k+l)` is equivalent to `A[b*k+l]`.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/R9zY3K)

Answer (score 3):

Lets take a close look at one of your loops (I use the input loop, but the error is in the output loop as well):

```
for(int i=0;i<=(x-1);i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=(y-1);j++)
    {
        printf("A(%d,%d)=",i+1,j+1);
        scanf("%d",(M+i+j));
    }
}
```

The first iteration of the outer loop, `i` is zero. Then the inner loop runs, and we read into (in turn) `M+0+0`, `M+0+1` and `M+0+2`.

Then we run the second iteration of the outer loop, where the inner loop will read into `M+1+0`, `M+1+1` and `M+1+2`.

In these two iterations of the outer loop you will read into `M+1` and `M+2` *twice*. That's because `M+0+1` and `M+1+0` are *the same element*.

---

To fix this, lets take a look at your "matrix" as it is in memory

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The numbers inside are the indexes. Now, `0`, `1` and `2` is the first row. `3`, `4` and `5` is the second. And `6`, `7` and `8` is the last.

From this we can see that to get to the next line, we have to add the number of columns.

From this we get the formula `line * number_of_columns + column` to get the index.

Putting it in place, your input loop could look like

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        printf("A(%d,%d)=",i+1,j+1);
        scanf("%d",M+i*y+j);
    }
}
```

Comment: `That's because M+0+1 and M+1+0 are the same element.` Wow I didn't know that. I thought `M+i+j` was synonymous to `&M[i][j]`. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 1):

To choose the address in which to write a value, you use:

```
M+i+j
```

Let's try that for a few values of `(i,j)`:

```
0,0  -> M + 0
0,1  -> M + 1
0,2  -> M + 2  // So far so good.
1,0  -> M + 1  // not right
1,1  -> M + 2  // not right
... etc.
```

You want `M + (i * x) + j`. For `x == 3`:

```
0,0  -> M + 0
0,1  -> M + 1
0,2  -> M + 2  
1,0  -> M + 3  
1,1  -> M + 4  
... etc.
```

The same goes for the pointer arithmetic when reading from the same memory.

---

Furthermore, since the pointer just goes up by one each time, you could get the same behaviour with:

```
int *m = M;
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=(y-1);j++)
    {
        printf("A(%d,%d)=",i+1,j+1);
        scanf("%d",m);
        m++;
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
for(int i=0; i<x*y; i++) {
   printf("A(%d,%d)=", i/3, i%3);
   scanf("%d", M + i);
}
```

---

Other points:

In one method you use variables `x,y,i,j`, and in another you use `a,b,k,l`. I assume you've done this because you don't want to overwrite one with the other. But because of *scope*, that's not a factor. `x` is local to the function `minput()` -- you can have another `x` in `main()` and they will be completely independent of one another. Use `x,y,i,j` in both places, because they are the "sensible" names for dimensions and loop counters.

`for(i=0; i<x; i++)` is the conventional way of looping `x` times. Your `i<=(x-1)` is equivalent but messy and confusing.

Casting the result of `malloc()` is discouraged nowadays. [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

```
int *M = malloc(x*y*sizeof(int));
```