# no matching function for call to 'maps::size(char [20], char&)' but I think that my method there is

Tags: c++

```
class maps{

public:

    int rows;
    int cols;
    void size(char **lvl, char corner);

private:

};

void maps::size(char **lvl, char corner){
    for(int c=0; *lvl[c]!=corner; c++){
        cols=c;
    }
    for (int r=0; *lvl[r * cols + 1]!=corner; r++){
         cols=r;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char w = 189; //wall
char e = 122; //entity
char y = 206; //you
char s = ' '; //space
char c = 188; //corner
control control_you;
maps map_level;
char lvl1[10][20]={{w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, c},
                   {w, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, w},
                   {w, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, w},
                   {w, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, w},
                   {w, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, w},
                   {w, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, w},
                   {w, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, w},
                   {w, s, e, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, w},
                   {w, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, y, w},
                   {c, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w}};
map_level.size(*lvl1, c);
    return 0;
 }
```

> Bloc[Error] no matching function for call to 'maps::size(char [20], char&)

I don't know why it cant finds my function, can you help me?
I don't know if I've done something wrong in the call of the function in my class or what, I'm desperate, please help me with that. Thank you.

Comment: Your function expects `char **` but you try to pass `char *`, you better use `std::string`

Comment: What @Slava said, either pass `lvl1` by itself, or better yet, use `std::string`.

Comment: I highly recommend using *character literals* rather than numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` but doing it your way I would change the `size()` method like this:

```
void size(char* lvl, char corner){
    rows = 0;
    cols = 0;

    for (int c=0; lvl[c] != corner; c++){
        ++cols;
    }
    ++cols;  // count the corner 

    for (int r=0; lvl[r * cols] != corner; r++){
        ++rows;
    }
    ++rows;  // count the corner 
}
```

where `cols` and `rows` is are the same as the `lvl1`, including the *corners*. And *hope* there are corners at the right places.

And call it like this:

```
map_level.size((char*)lvl1, c);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07ffd9c1bcd97095)

[How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2565039/8918119)