# How can I set every element of a boolean matrix to false without a loop

Tags: c++

```
bool vizitat[60][60];

...

if(/*some condition*/)
{
    vizitat[n][m] = {0}; // set all the elements to `false`.
    /*other code here*/
}
```

Is there a way of setting every element of `vizitat` to 0, ideally without an explicit loop?

Comment: `memset(vizitat, 0, sizeof vizitat);` is one way

Comment: As for your problem, please read about [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) and [`std::memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset). Or just initialize it at definition with e.g. `bool vizitat[60][60] = { { false } };`

Comment: I was just reading out of curiosity and I found out I did not know that worked lol! @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

Since `vizitat` is declared as `bool vizitat[60][60];`,

```
std::fill(
    &vizitat[0][0]/*the first element*/,
    &vizitat[0][0] + sizeof visitat / sizeof(bool) /*one after the last element*/,
    false
);
```

would do it.

This is because the data in the array are contiguous. Using `std::memset` is not safe in general although a compiler might optimise to that.

Note that this approach would not work if the memory was allocated, say, *row-by-row*. For more details see [How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

Comment: note: `memset` on bools is not safe. There could be some architecture where, in memory, `false = -1` and `true = 0`. And `sizeof(bool)` need not be 1. But this would probably work. I would do `std::fill(&vizitat[0][0], &vizitat[0][0] + (sizeof vizitat / sizeof(bool)), false)`, which would `memset` on most systems anyways.