# Understanding strcpy and char arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

Why does strcpy work in the following example using a 2d character array:

```
int main(void) {
    char words[2][6] = {"Hello", "World"};
    strcpy(words[0], words[1]);
    printf("%s \n", words[0]);
}
```

But causes a segmentation fault in this example which uses an array of pointers to char arrays:

```
int main(void) {
    char * words[2] = {"Hello", "World"};
    strcpy(words[0], words[1]);
    printf("%s \n", words[0]);
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Oh ok - and in the first case they are not string literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not because of [`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) - it does the same thing in both cases: It copies characters in sequence from the source to corresponding positions at the destination location until the `\0` at the end of the source string.

The reason you're getting a segmentation fault in the second case is that those string literals are now in a different segment of memory, which is *read only* (e.g. it could be together with the compiled program text). When `strcpy()` tries to write characters in there, your process gets interrupted and the kernel tells you "You can't do that, you're violating the segmentation of memory" (hence a segmentation violation or fault).

In the *first* case, those read-only string literals still exist, but you're using them to initialize a local variable - the (two dimensional) array, which is located on the stack. The two-dimensional array is *not* an array of pointers, it is actually an array of characters, and C just "arranges" the accesses to that array so that you can use pairs of square brackets.

See:

- [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2589949/1593077)
- [How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)
- [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

here on StackOverflow, for more on these topics.

Comment: That makes sense. In the first case (the 2d char array) on the other hand, where are the strings stored?

Comment: @Ishmael7: I said "located on the stack"... I've added a link about that.