# C, dynamic array, segmentation fault

Tags: c

I wanted to allocate memory and scanf array in one function, but it gives segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Thank you for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void scanf_array (int **array_pp, int size);

int main ()
{
  int *array_p, size;
  scanf ("%d", &size);
  scanf_array (&array_p, size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf ("%d", array_p[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}

void scanf_array (int **array_pp, int size)
{
  *array_pp = (int *)malloc (size * sizeof (int));
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
  scanf ("%d", array_pp[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `array_pp[i]` is not even in array you've allocated. Also you need to provide `scanf` with address of the element, not its value. Should be something like `&(*array_pp)[i]`.

Comment: read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory/59691323#59691323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf ("%d", array_pp[i]);
```

is wrong. `int **array_pp` is meant to be pointer to an array of `int`s. So you want to dereference the pointer, then pass the address of `i`th element to `scanf`:

```
scanf ("%d", &(*array_pp)[i]);
scanf ("%d", (*array_pp) + i);  // means the same
```

Remember to `free(array_p)`.

Because sometimes using pointer to pointer sematics is hard, it's sometimes clearer to use a temp pointer for me:

```
void scanf_array (int **array_pp, int size)
{
  int *array_p = malloc(size * sizeof (*array_p));
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     scanf ("%d", &array_p[i]);
  }
  *array_pp = array_p;
}
```

Comment: A short discussion on why the `(..)` are needed and a link to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) may help further.

Answer (score 1):

Is scanf ("%d", &(*array_pp)[i]); you're looking for?

Comment: It's more than 10 years since I've worked with C++ so probably my memory is getting a bit rusty. My way of thinking was that [] operator is a simple memory address offset array[i] == array + i, but to think of it you're right, array[i] == *(array + i), sorry it's been a while

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line:

`scanf ("%d", array_pp[i]);`

The expression `array_pp[i]` would be correct if `array_pp` was a pointer to the first element of an array. However, it is a pointer to a single variable of type `int *`. Since a single variable is equivalent to an array of size 1, the only permissible index that is not out of bounds would be `array_pp[0]`. However, for single variables, it is common to write `*array_pp` instead, even if it accomplishes exactly the same thing as `array_pp[0]`. This is because indexing is generally only used with "proper" arrays, i.e. arrays with at least 2 elements.

The expression `*array_pp` (or `array_pp[0]` if you prefer) gives you access to the variable

`int *array_p`

from the function main. Since that pointer now points to the first element of a dynamically allocated array of type `int`, you can use the indexes `0` to `size` on that pointer. So you could write either

`(*array_pp)[i]`

or

`array_pp[0][i]`

in your loop, where `i` is a value between `0` and `size`.

As stated before, even if both expressions accomplish exactly the same thing, it is better to write `(*array_pp)[i]` instead of `array_pp[0][i]`.

However, the function `scanf()` requires the **address of** the array element to write to. So the line should be changed to the following:

`scanf ("%d", &(*array_pp)[i]);`