# How to find mode of a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, multidimensional-array, frequency

If I have a multidimensional array, like `a[i][j]`, what is the most plausible way to find the mode of elements of the array?

Comment: what do you mean by "mode" -> modulo? or Type? and C or C++?

Comment: Convert to a 1D array. Sort. Count.

Comment: Isn't a  multidimensional array a collection of one-dimensional arrays? Find mode for the individual arrays and store them in a vector. The highest value in this vector can be taken as the mode.

Answer (score 2):

To find the mode of the values of the matrix: first, you need to convert the 2D array to a 1D array; second, sort the values of the array; and then, identify the value that appears with the higher frequency (consecutively) in the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int sort(const void* xx, const void* yy)
{
  int x = *((int*)xx);
  int y = *((int*)yy);

  if (x < y)
    return -1;
  if (x > y)
    return +1;

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{

  int i, freq, max_freq, mode;

  int a[4][3] = { { 1, 4, 5 }, { 3, 2, 4 }, { 5, 5, 2 }, { 4, 4, 2 } };
  int v[4 * 3];

  // 1. Convert 2D to 1D
  for (i = 0; i < 4 * 3; i++) {
    v[i] = a[i % 4][i / 4];
  }

  // 2. Sort the array
  qsort(v, 4 * 3, sizeof(int), sort);

  for (i = 1, freq = 1, max_freq = 0; i < 4 * 3; i++) {

    if (v[i - 1] == v[i]) {

      // 3. If consecutive values are equal,
      //    increment by 1 the frequency of the value
      freq++;

      if (freq > max_freq) {

        // 3. If the value has a higher frequency than
        //    the saved one, save the current value.
        max_freq = freq;
        mode = v[i];
      }
    } else {
      // 3. Since it is a new value, restart the frequency count.
      freq = 1;
    }
 }

  printf("Mode %d\n", mode);

  return 0;
}
```

This returns:

```
Mode 4
```

Comment: Will this work for rectangular matrices too?
`// 1. Convert 2D to 1D
  for (i = 0; i < 3 * 3; i++) {
    v[i] = a[i % 3][i / 3];
  }`

Comment: @NoobCoder The more general solution that doesn't require any math is `k = 0; for(i=0;i<rows;i++) for(j=0;j<cols;j++) v[k++] = a[i][j];`

Comment: @NoobCoder I have updated the answer for non-rectangular matrices.

Comment: @user3386109   `for (i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)  v[i] = a[i % rows][i / rows];` is also valid for general cases, but probably your approach is better understood by a beginner.

Comment: If you do not need the matrix `a` later, you could skip the 2D to 1D conversion and replace `v` with `a` in the code. This can be done because multi-dimensional arrays are stored contiguously in memory, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565048/13473361) discussion. In this case, basically, finding the mode in a multidimensional array is the same as finding the mode in a simple array.