# Pointers and Multi dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Consider a 3 dimensinal array initialized as
`int C[3][2][2];`
With elements as
1,2.....12 and memory locations starting from 800 (say) .

Please give the output of ,and  explain me the meaning of -
`*(C[1]+1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

Comment: The number of bytes added by the `+1` in `(C[1]+1)` is the size of `C[1]` which with 32-bit `int` is `16`.

Comment: Also, see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)