# I'm having trouble with my function for finding the lowest value in a 5x5 two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>



using namespace std;  

void displayArray(int elements[][5], int numCol, int numRow) {
    for (int row = 0; row < numRow; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numCol; col++) {
            cout << elements[row][col] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

int findMin(int arr[], int n) {
    
    int mini = arr[0];


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < mini) {
            mini = arr[i];
        }

        return { mini };
    }
}

    int findMax(int arr[], int n) {
        
        int maxi = arr[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > maxi) {
                maxi = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return { maxi };
    }

 int main()
 {
     const int numCol = 5;
     const int numRow = 5;
     int elements[numCol][numRow] = { { 81, 27, 83, 89, 92}, {87, 76, 84, 98, 99}, {83, 47, 89, 42, 48}, {75, 96, 76, 34 ,38}, {98, 83, 76, 27, 29} };

     int N = sizeof(elements) / sizeof(elements[0]);
    
     displayArray(elements, numCol, numRow);
     

     cout << "Minimum is: " << findMin(elements, N);

 }
```

So currently, when executing this code I get an error specifying that my parameters are incompatible C++ argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type. I'm currently stuck as to why I'm getting this issue. My hypothesis is that I cannot do this with a normal array, and may have to use a vector array in order to, achieve the end goal of producing the smallest number in the array and the largest.

Comment: Recommendation: Reproduce the error message verbatim as text. It speed things up greatly and makes the question easer to find for future askers with the same problem.

Comment: You are attempting to pass a two-dimensional array to a function that takes a single dimension array, or a plain pointer, as a parameter. This is not allowed in C++, C++ simply does not work this way. Additionally, once you fix this compilation error, you will discover that `N` is not 25, but 5. Perhaps this will be a useful hint to you as to what the underlying fundamental problem is.

Comment: A 2D array does not decay to a pointer to `int`. It decays to a pointer to an array of `int` (`int (*)[5]` in this case)

Comment: `return { mini };`  is inside the for() loop. Meaning it ends your function on the first iteration. I voted to close as a trivial typo.

Comment: *I'm having trouble with my function for finding the lowest value in a 5x5 two dimensional array* `std::cout << *std::min_element(&elements[0][0], &elements[numCol-1][numRow]);`.  A 2D-array lays out the data contiguously.

Comment: [The full compiler error makes the problem reasonably clear](https://godbolt.org/z/Pq1dE5d5s), though the suggestion from Visual Studio of using a cast is a questionable. Examine the diagnostic messages carefully and your job is usually easier. Much easier once you get more used to interpreting the diagnostics, but that comes with practice.

Comment: `std::array` can be passed to functions without such pain

Comment: Either you have a 2D array, or you have a 1D array. You cannot have the same array both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Since two-dimensional arrays have a contiguous memory layout, they are actually one-dimensional arrays under the the hood.

Thus you can still call your `findMin` and `findMax` functions without changing their signatures.  The trick is to pass the address of the first element of the 2D array:

```
int findMin(int arr[], int n) 
{
  //...
}

int main()
{
     const int numCol = 5;
     const int numRow = 5;
     int elements[numCol][numRow] = { { 81, 27, 83, 89, 92}, {87, 76, 84, 98, 99}, {83, 47, 89, 42, 48}, {75, 96, 76, 34 ,38}, {98, 83, 76, 27, 29} };
     int N = sizeof(elements) / sizeof(elements[0]);
     displayArray(elements, numCol, numRow);

     // Note that we are using the address of the first item
     cout << "Minimum is: " << findMin(&elements[0][0], N);
}
```

---

The second issue is that your `findMin` function is wrong.  You are returning prematurely instead of returning after the `for` loop is completed.

Instead of doing all of that work, use `std::min_element`:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
int findMin(int arr[], int n) 
{
    return *std::min_element(arr, arr + n);
}
```

The same with `findMax`, except use `std::max_element`:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
int findMax(int arr[], int n) 
{
    return *std::max_element(arr, arr + n);
}
```

Note, there were no `std::vector`'s being used -- everything used the original 2D array.

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/efqc13MxE)

Comment: It is Undefined Behaviour to tread a 2D array as one big 1D array.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but I always thought that C++ would follow C in terms of memory layout of 2D arrays.  Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory) suggesting as such.  If I'm wrong, then ok, I learned something today.

Comment: It is UB in C too. The C standard text has a very explicit mention of it in the list of all the UBs: "An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration `int a[4][5]`) (6.5.6)."